# Laptop "do nothing" does not work

Tags: 12.04, power-management

I've just installed 12.04 on my laptop.

At home, I use an external monitor and keyboard and would like to close the lid on my laptop. In settings under **Power**, I've selected "Do nothing" for when the lid is closed, for both 'on battery' and 'plugged in', but the computer suspends every time.

What do I need to do to work with the lid closed?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it too and the laptop suspends when closing the lid.
This is a confirmed bug at launchpad. Maybe you can find a solution [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpi/+bug/49521).